# Android SDK 30 - Microphone records nothing while device goes to sleep and starts recording when it is woken up

Tags: android, microphone

This Android app I am working on records audio for over 6 hours. When It was compiled with SDK 29, the app records fine even when the device goes to sleep. However, once I compiled it with SDK 33, the microphone records silence after the device goes to sleep and then records fine again when the Device wakes up. Any idea how to fix this?

The microphone recording is started by a foreground service that has this:             android:foregroundServiceType="microphone".

I read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#bg-access-restriction-exemptions), but it is for foreground service that started the recording while the app is in the background. This app starts the recording while it is in the Foreground.

I am inclined to start the service with [long-running workers](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/long-running#foreground-service-type). But, that is a huge change to the existing code. I wanted to pick some brains before investing time in this. Any tips?

Comment: Are you holding a wakelock?

Comment: Is there a chance its related to app standby buckets putting the app in a lowwer rated bucket so you don't get the resources in the background. I've had similar with playing audio. https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't know if UX will allow me to keep the wake lock as this app records audio during the night and they would not want a screen light.

Comment: @Chris It is working fine on the same device when built with SDK 29.

Comment: A wakelock does not necessarily keep the screen on. Moreover, if the CPU goes to sleep, your code will not run.

Comment: And you're sure there were no changes regarding App standby buckets between those versions? A lot of changes regarding user privacy and permissions in recent times.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out why. The Service that was dealing with Audio Recording was not started as a Foreground service as expected. The code that is supposed to change that Service to a foreground service was skipped because of an exception (Pending Intent should have FLAG_IMMUTABLE or the other) introduced in SDK 31. And that exception was swallowed due to bad coding practices. The Pending intent creation was happening inside the Nav library. So, I had to upgrade the Nav Library and Gradle Version to resolve it.